# My App getting crashed when pressing any of four buttons

Tags: android, crash

I am getting problem with my application.it is crashing on pressing any of the button.

I have used float conversion of string object.

My MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView tv1,tv2;
    EditText et1;
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1=findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2=findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        et1=findViewById(R.id.et1);
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3=findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4=findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv2.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        String value=et1.getText().toString();
        int newvalue=Integer.parseInt(value);
        int thirdvalue=0;

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn1:
                thirdvalue = (int) (newvalue*37.98f);
                tv2.setText(thirdvalue);
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                thirdvalue = (int) (newvalue*45.47f);
                tv2.setText(thirdvalue);
                break;

            case R.id.btn3:
                thirdvalue = (int) (newvalue*50.52f);
                tv2.setText(thirdvalue);
                break;

            case R.id.btn4:
                thirdvalue = (int) (newvalue*63.16f);
                tv2.setText(thirdvalue);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get result on pressing any of the button and give result as per pressed button.

It is giving this error in my logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 14892
>                     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3b5
>                         at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:328)
>                         at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:125)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4432)
>                         at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14892 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Comment: Replace all statements like `tv2.setText(thirdvalue);` with `tv2.setText("" + thirdvalue);`

Comment: Thank you@forpas .it works.

Answer (score 2):

you cant add integer value in setText method. 
Try with `tv2.setText(thirdvalue + "");` or `tv2.setText(String.valueOf(thirdvalue));`

Read up on setText() method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))

Answer (score 2):

replace all `tv2.setText(thirdvalue);` with `tv2.setText(String.valueOf(thirdvalue));`

and you don't need to add this`(tv2.findViewById(R.id.tv2);)` in onClick method

Answer (score 1):

add String.valueOf(thirdValue) because probably he is searching for id instead of setting the text

```
tv2.setText(String.valueOf(thirdvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the argument of setText() as String so change your code to

```
tv2.setText(thirdvalue.toString);
```

and same for the remaining buttons as well. This will make it as a String.